# wxWidgets drawing transparency issue

Tags: bitmap, wxwidgets

Below is the relevant lines of code. Essentially what I do is create a larger bitmap, draw to this, and then create a smaller image from that and draw it to the screen (wxDC mdc). In order to get it transparent I first use a wxMemoryDC and wxGCDC since this is the only way i could figure out how.

The issue is that, it works perfectly unless the clipped out sub_bmp has nothing drawn to it, then it just draws a black background instead of transparent.

Any ideas?

```
*bmp = wxBitmap(bwidth, bheight, 32);       
bmp->UseAlpha();
wxColor colour;
colour.Set("#800020");
penWidth = 4;
mdc->SetPen(wxPen(colour, penWidth));
wxMemoryDC memDC (*bmp);
wxGCDC dc(memDC);
dc.SetBackground(*wxTRANSPARENT_BRUSH);
dc.Clear();

dc.SetBrush(*wxRED_BRUSH);
dc.SetPen(wxPen(colour, penWidth));
...
b1.x = pix_offset_x - (cpix.x - b1.x);                  
b1.y = pix_offset_y - (cpix.y - b1.y);
b2.x = pix_offset_x - (cpix.x - b2.x);
b2.y = pix_offset_y - (cpix.y - b2.y);

dc.DrawLine(b1, b2);
memDC.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);           //releases the bitmap from memDC
wxRect subSize(xloc,yloc , vp->pix_width*scaleFactor, vp->pix_height*scaleFactor);
wxBitmap sub_bmp = bmp->GetSubBitmap(subSize);
wxImage tmpimg = sub_bmp.ConvertToImage();
const wxBitmap tbmp(tmpimg.Scale(t_width, t_height),32);
mdc->DrawBitmap(tbmp, 0, 0, true);
```

Comment: are you doing this inside EVT_PAINT? If yes - did you create wxPaintDC? If no - you should do this inside EVT_PAINT as every new paint event will overwrite you bitmap.

Comment: bmp is declared globally in the .h file and I am given a wxDC from the core program I am writing a plugin from. That is what mdc is. I don't create a wxPiantDC.

Comment: but you do you painting from EVT_PAINT as you should, correct? In which case you have to create wxPaintDC, even if it will not be used. Or you are saying that you mdc is a wxPaintDC object?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a recent version of wxWidgets, you can draw directly to the wxImage but first you must setup the alpha channel.

Then the image can be scaled and copied to the provided mdc as you are doing currently.

```
// Setup the alpha channel.
unsigned char* alphaData = new unsigned char[bwidth * bheight];
memset (alphaData, wxIMAGE_ALPHA_TRANSPARENT, bwidth * bheight);

// Create an image with alpha.
wxImage image (wxSize(bwidth, bheight));
image.SetAlpha (alphaData);
wxGraphicsContext* gc = wxGraphicsContext::Create (image);

gc->SetPen (wxPen(colour, penWidth));
gc->SetBrush (wxTRANSPARENT_BRUSH);

// Do drawing here ....

// Release the graphics context.
delete gc;

// Scale the image and convert to a bitmap.
wxBitmap outBmp (image.Scale(t_width, t_height), 32);

// Blit it to the provide mdc.
mdc->DrawBitmap (outBmp, wxPoint(x,y)), true);
```

Comment: By the way, `image.SetAlpha` can take NULL as a parameter to avoid the `alphaData` memory allocation step, but I am not sure how it initialises the alpha channel in that case so I prefer to do it myself.